# py-cord button not working even after being defined

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

so i am trying to run this code in repl.it after installing py-cord but it gives the following error

```py
if message.content.startswith('$vote'):
      vote = discord.Embed(
        title= message.author.name,
        url="https://discord.gg/NVW8jbmmz",
        description= message.author.name + " you can vote for me by clicking the vote button, may the god add one more day to your life for every vote" 
      )
      button = [
        Button(style=ButtonStyle.URL, label="Vote Here ", url="https://top.gg/bot/749932591892660324/vote")
      ] 
      await message.channel.send(embed=vote, components= button)
```

error says that button is not defined but i had defined the button

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 253, in on_message
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.URL, label="Vote Here ", url="https://top.gg/bot/749932591892660324/vote")
NameError: name 'Button' is not defined
```

Comment: Where did you define `Button`? Don't see it in your code.

Comment: I think replacing `Button(style=....)` with `discord_components.Button(style=....)` should work, unless `discord_components.Button` is imported.